# To display the records retrieved from database into a dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dialog

I have a dialog box which takes a number input.I want to send this number to database and retrieve the name corresponding to that number and display it into another dialog box.My code works fine till retrieving the data but I don't know how to display it into another dialog box.I have created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/payalsuthar/rdtpo7e3/
and here is dataretrieve.php-

```
 <?php
    include('db.php');
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    $sql = "SELECT `no`,`name` FROM `table` WHERE `no` = $num ";
     if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){ 
    //i dont know how to display the values retrieved here into my dialog2(you can check my dialog2)
   }
 ?>
```

Html code-

```
<form action="dataretrieve.php" method="POST">
<div id="dialog1" title="div1" style="display:none"> 
Enter the num:<input type="text" name="num" id="num" />
</div>
</form>
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
<div id="dialog2" title="div1" style="display:none"> 
num:<input type="text" name="number" id="number" />
```

JavaScript code-

```
$("#clickMe").click(function(){

$('#dialog1').dialog({
buttons:{
"yes":function(){
$(this).dialog('close');
callback(true);
},
"no":function(){
$(this).dialog('close');
}
}
});
function callback(value){
if(value){
$('#dialog2').dialog({
buttons:{
"ok":function(){
$(this).dialog('close');
},
"cancel":function(){
$(this).dialog('close');
}
}
});
}
}
});
```

Comment: If you want to display the result on the same page without reload, you have to use ajax (`http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will look something like this (untested):

<kbd>[**jQuery Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1xjn5r8r/)</kbd>

**PHP:** Use `echo` to send the data back to javascript side

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    $num = $_POST['number'];
    $sql = "SELECT `no`,`name` FROM `table` WHERE `no` = $num ";
    if($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){ 
        $out = $result['yourDBfieldname'];
        echo $out; //THIS sends it back to javascript side
    }
?>
```

**HTML:** No need to use a `<form>` construct -- AJAX is what you need

```
<div id="dialog1"> 
    Enter the num:<input type="text" name="num" id="num" />
    <button id="submit1">Submit</button>
</div>
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
var num, nam;
$("#clickMe").click(function(){
    $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
});
$("#submit1").click(function(){
    $('#dialog1').dialog('close');
    num = $('#num').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
         url: 'dataretrieve.php',
        data: 'number=' +num,
        success: function(recd){
            //if (recd.length) alert(recd);
            $('#dialog1').html('<input id="name" type="text" value="'+recd+'" /><button id="submit2">Submit</button>');
            $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
        }
    });
});
//Must use .on() because content injected after DOM initially rendered
$(document).on('click', '#submit2', function(){
    $('#dialog1').dialog('close');
    nam = $('#name').val();
    alert('Num: '+num+ '    Name: ' + nam);
});


//Initialize the jQuery dialog - makes the #dialog1 div hidden
$('#dialog1').dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    buttons:{
        "Close":function(){
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

---

Note:

No need for two dialogs. You can re-use the one dialog by changing the content inside the `#dialog1` div, via the `.html()` method.

Comment: ,Can you tell me what does 'd' stands for in --- if (d.length) alert(recd);

Comment: Sorry, that was an error. I usually use `d` as the var name for data received from the PHP side. To make the code more obvious, I renamed that to `rcvd` in the above example, but forgot to change that line. The line should also be commented out -- I leave it there to demonstrate a handy troubleshooting technique that I use often. *Code updated.*

Comment: thanks a lot...it worked for me...Can you please let me know how can i retrieve multiple values from database ,as for now it is only retrieving name.I tried for date as well but it is showing both the values in same input box and how do i save the edited values in database on the click of "OK" button of dialog box @gibberish

Comment: No time to answer right now, so for best / fastest answer please ask that as a new question. You will get dozens of people reading the question and trying to help right away, instead of waiting on me to have time. *Best wishes with your project* Thanks for the checkmark and upvote. :)